# Frequent 'Spurous retransmissions'

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy

I have the following setup:

[image]

At peak Wifi traffic, I see that some sites on the internet are re-sending packets needlessly, triggering 'Spurious re-transmission' messages in Wireshark. This finally results in Time-outs, and loss of connection.

I suspect that the internet sites are not allowing for the extra delays 'behind the scenes' of the wifi link, and just re-transmits. Is this a correct assumption?

As I don't have control over the Internet sites' behaviour, I suspect I could improve the situation installing a proxy in the server which ACKs the site's packets and takes of the Wifi links. Maybe a program like TinyProxy? (I have a solid connection to the sites from the Server).

Or is there other tweaking which can be done before installing the proxy?

(Note: I am not a network expert - and the setup is a small-scale home setup. Machines are Linux)

Comment: Spurious retransmissions are packets received by a client which it has already sent an Acknowledgement for. If this is happening at peak times its possible you have congestion issues on the network and packets are being dropped. WiFi should not be introducing latency issues unless something is really wrong.

Comment: During a peak time, go to http://dslreports.com/speedtest to check for bufferbloat issues. If something on your network is letting long queues of buffered packets build up instead of letting things drop, it keeps TCP Congestion Control from working, so things get worse and worse. This is called bufferbloat. Also, note that spurious retransmissions are probably just another symptom, not the cause, of your timeouts and connection losses. The cause could be a buggy or overloaded AP, or a too-busy radio channel. Try with a different, higher-quality AP on a cleaner channel.